# Force dom to update onclick attribute in firefox 3.5.3

Tags: jquery, events, dom, struts2, triggers

Here is the problem i am facing:
i have an input to sumbit a form with a function executed in a click event.
This function will disable the event click, launch a jquery dialog box.
the dialog box has a yes/no buttons, which will empty onclick attr out of the input (the prevent rexecution of the function), and trigger a click event for it to submit the form.
this works fine in firefox 17, but in firefox 3.5.3 it triggers the function execution even if the onclick attr has been emptied out.
i suspect that has to do with the dom update, but i am not sure.

here is a snippet of the algorithm:

```
<form>
  ....
<s:submit action="someAction" onClick="myFunction(this,'save_box_id'); return false;"/>

function myFunction(sauvButton,save_box_id) {

          if($("#save_box_id").is(':data(dialog)')){

              $("#save_box_id").dialog('open');
          }else{
              $("#save_box_id").dialog({
                  buttons:{
                      "Yes":function(){
                                      ...
                          $(sauvButton).attr('onclick','');
                          $(sauvButton).trigger('click');
                          $(this).dialog('close');
                      },
                      "No": function(){
                         ...
                          $(sauvButton).attr('onclick','');
                          $(this).dialog('close');
                          $(sauvButton).trigger('click');



                      },
                      "cancel":function(){
                          $(this).dialog('close'); 
                      }
                  }

              });
          }

 }
```

thanks for your responses.

Comment: Why do you even have to fiddle with `onclick` when you're using jQuery?

Comment: Because, i want to change the behavior of the input which was just clicked and launched the function, to be clicked again, but this time to accomplish its normal behavior: submitting the form.